# Component requires type annotation only when used as root of exported component

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Flow requires me to annotate a component if I'm gonna use it inside an exported component, but this happens only if the un-annotated component is rendered as root of the exported component.

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';

const ContainerA = props => <div {...props} />;

// This one throws "Missing type annotation for `props`."
const ContainerB = props => <div {...props} />;

type Props = { children: React$Node };


// No type error
export const Ok = (props: Props) => <><ContainerA>{props.children}</ContainerA></>;

// Type error (see ContainerB comment)
export const Ko = (props: Props) => <ContainerB>{props.children}</ContainerB>;
```

[Flow-Try repro](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gEoCmAhgMZ6RayqgDkWJ5tA3IoqbAHYDOeAwlxzFknQlgCCoALyh0VdN2kA+UAB4AJsgBuoAN4A6Q3NgKAvqGBLW7Lr1ADOQkWIBC02fMVSVG7XsP6xmYWVmw4AJ7ohKAACp7uuqCkABbI0OoMnABcBIw4ACQAcrDq0abWiIQAHpi4SbZ4APIA1u4AFEHcOXEm3ACUympKqg5OohJKup36KWkZhJymqsCjwuPiw5bW1bV4HDx4ANKw7Z3dngPeaqvOWC6T07PpmUsrgmuuVkA)

If I wrap the un-annotated component with something else (a fragment, a div, etc), then Flow doesn't require me to annotate it.

I know Flow wants us to annotate the exported functions, components, etc... but I'm not exporting that component, I'm using it inside a component that's getting exported.

Why is it behaving this way?

Answer (score 0):

flow needs to know arguments and the return type of an exported function.

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gFSgCGAzqAEoCmRAxnpFrKqAORbV0sDciiNsAOxJ4AwoJxFkAylgCCoALyh0jdGQUA+UAB4AJsgBuoAN4A6cythqAvqGAaefQcNBiBEqTIBCi5avVaeoYm5qaWNnYOvDgAnuiUoAAK-r7GoDQAFsjQuuwCAFwUHDgAJABysLoJ1o6IlAAemLjpzngA8gDWvgAU4SSFyVYkAJSKgRrabh7SchrGfaaZ2bmUAtbawFOSM7IT9o4NTXj8QngA0rA9fQP+w4VUtDimFVVjOlueWF5zC0s5eetNuJtt4HEA)

It seems, when you use build-in things like react fragments or `div` flow can infer the return type without explicit annotation.